# C++/SDL2 IMG_Load Error (Out of memory)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am making a shoot'em up game and have been coming into a problem where the sprites won't load at all after a certain amount of time and continuously shooting. In my console, an error prints out:

"IMG_LOAD_ERROR : Out of memory" (The "IMG_LOAD_ERROR : " was my own thing)

I also use text (SDL_ttf) to display an ammo count.

The hypothesis I have now is that I always call the IMG_load function in the constructor of every enemy that is spawned, but I'm not even sure if that's what's causing it. There are quite a few more possibilities I can think of.

Also, I do free the textures when they are destroyed (when the enemy is out of health or leaves the screen).

Can someone help me understand this and help me fix it?

Comment: I'm surprised you acknowledge that you have not provided code and yet still do not provide code. Do you realise that we're asking for your code to figure out what is wrong with it?

Comment: Is it happens on the same single image or at some time after program running? If latter, you're probably not freeing memory you've allocated before (see @Novros answer). If valgrind can run on your OS, it is probably easiest tool to find that kind of mistakes. If not - there are alternatives specifically designed to find leaks, but they may not be as verbose and straightforward as valgrind. Seeing source code would be nice, but if you know that and still didn't posted the code - I suspect it might be too big for the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not destroying textures/images or renderes that you are not need.

SDL_DestroyTexture(img);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);

Simple example of drawing image, which i found https://gist.github.com/armornick/3434362.

My advice: You should load all textures or begin of application or when is needed, but it must be once. You must reuse every same image.

It would be nice to see code to find out, what is wrong with code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am freeing memory in the enemy destructor.*facepalm* Sorry about that :|.